# PhpWord funciona de manera local pero en el hosting envia error 500

Tags: phpword

Buen día.

Tengo el problema con la librería **PhpWord**, de manera local me genera el `docx`, pero cuando lo subo a mi `server` me manda error:

> HTTP ERROR 500

He visto que de forma local tengo `PHP` Versión **5.6.36**
y en el hosting `PHP` Versión **7.2.15**.

Si bajo la versión del `PHP` el el hosting (por ejemplo al `PHP` Versión **5.6.40**), si me genera el documento de word, pero en el inicio de sesión no me deja entrar (no pasa del `login` ) y no arroja ningún error.

Que podría ser, la documentación del **PhpWord** dice que aceptar `PHP` **5.3.3** para arriba.

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución que encontré fue cambiar la forma que utilizaba el header location en php.

Deje el php en la version que me generaba el .docx PHP Version 5.6.40

y cambie la forma de redireccionar en el login

```
case '3': header('location:menu.php'); break;
```

por js:

```
case '3': ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              window.location.href='menu.php';
            </script>
<?php break;
```

lo he probado en el hosting y me esta funcionando, quedo abierto a mejores sugerencias.